# How can we Exclude the unnecessary rows from Excel File while doing Data Load using Copy activity in ADF

Tags: xls, azure-data-lake, data-ingestion, azure-data-factory

I have a excel file which is semi-structured. There is data in a table, but there are dividers in certain rows that should needs to be ignored.
The processing of the data should start with the column headers(Col1 , col2 ....)  and only process the rows with actual data.
Could anyone suggest the way to achieve this using copy activity in adf .

My source is xls file and target is ADLA (Parquet file)

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Hi @Parul, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Leon Yue thanks for response and  your answer was helpful though I used data flow to remove the dividers using filter and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The most closest solution is that you need manually choose data range in the excel file:
[image]

[image]

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-excel#dataset-properties

HTH.